# Calling the merge() method in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, persistent

Does `merge()` in Hibernate save data in the database or just attach the object to persistent state? Is it necessary to call the `update()` method to persist the state subsequently?

Comment: This question got some negative reviews and it was downvoted, but all this happened before I edited it. Maybe it's a better question now than it was before I edited it.

Comment: If you want to save your modifications at any time with out knowing about the state of an session, then use `merge()` in hibernate. And you need to call `update()` to save modifications in database.

Answer (score 1):

merge() just add object to transaction unit and any operation after that will be  part of change log in memory. update has to be called explicitly in order to persist state.